# Mean of a pixel value

Tags: java, image, image-processing

I am trying to understand the theory behind my method that calculates the mean colour value of an image.

I am using java's Color class and accessing the pixels and retriving their RGB values. Each pixel can be thought of as a vector. The vector has a red value, a green value and a blue value. When finding the mean of the red pixels in an image using getRed(). Does the method access a pixel, calculate the mean of the three colours in the vector and return that as the mean value for that pixel, then move on to the next pixel and do the same until it has accessed all the pixels and then find an over all mean of the pixel values summed divided by the total number of pixel values?

OR

Does getRed() simply sum the three features in the vector and return the total and move on to the next pixel and do the same. Before dividing by the total pixel value.

so, as an example:

is it:

((R+G+B)/3) + ((R+G+B)/3) + ((R+G+B)/3) + ((R+G+B)/3) + ((R+G+B)/3)) / 5

OR

((R+G+B)) + ((R+G+B)) + ((R+G+B)) + ((R+G+B)) + ((R+G+B))) / 5

Thanks in advance

Comment: [`getRed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#getRed--) will return the red component. Why on earth did you think `getRed()` will sum the elements that are not red?

Comment: So, get red accesses each pixel and gets the red component of the vector and the access the next pixel and get the red component of that vector... n times and then sums all these values / by the number of them and that is the mean red value? @MikeCAT

Comment: @user1167596 What class/method are you talking about specifically? I would expect `getRed()` should only access the red color value of a specific pixel.

Comment: Correct: "Each pixel can be thought of as a vector".  But: "When finding the mean of the red pixels in an image using getRed()"... *WHAT MAKES  YOU THINK THAT???*  STRONG SUGGESTION: read this article, about "color spaces" ... and the pros/cons of RGB vs. HSV vs. other numeric representations for "color": https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DrawColor/Concepts/AboutColorSpaces.html

Comment: Also: re-read the Java doc for what Color.getRed() and friends actually do (and don't do).  It does *not* compute some kind of "mean" of adjacent pixels!  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want the mean color of an image, then the method is:

Go though each pixel in the image

- keep a running sum the red values (getRed())
- keep a running sum the green values
- keep a running sum the blue values
- keep a running total of the number of pixels

**Average color** = (red total / total pixels), (green total / total pixels), (blue total / total pixels)

### Example

Let's say you have the following 4 pixel image:

```
[ (3, 1, 8) ] [ (4, 7, 0) ]

[ (1, 5, 9) ] [ (5, 1, 6) ]
```

**Average red value** = (3 + 4 + 1 + 5) / 4 = 3.25

**Average blue value** = (1 + 7 + 5 + 1) / 4 = 3.5

**Average green value** = (8 + 0 + 9 + 6) / 4 = 5.75

**Average color** = (3.25, 3.5, 5.75) // Just decide how you want to round the numbers